# How to make one column get narrower before the other when the browser window is narrowed

Tags: css, responsive-design

Consider the following layout:

There are 2 columns that have their `min-width` and `max-width` set (different for each one). When the user agent is narrowed, the right column starts getting narrower, while the left one remains the initial width. After the right column is at its `min-width`, the left one starts to get more narrow, until it is, too, at its `min-width`.

Is it possible to achieve this effect using CSS only? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be possible if you use [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

Put a static width on the left column in your base style. Then inside a media query which becomes active at a certain screen width, eg: `@media all and (max-device-width: 460px), (max-width: 460px)`, give it a smaller `min-width`.

The "certain screen width" should be the screen width at which your right column reaches its min-width.

Example here: http://jsbin.com/ivodam/1/edit

Comment: Seems about right! Could you please provide some CSS, as I'm very inexperienced with media queries?

Comment: sure, I added an example link to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible, though, to get rid of that sudden change at the moment the media query kicks in?

Comment: Not really. You can add more width queries to try and force a smooth transition, or you can use [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) (try a value like `all 0.5s ease 0s` and see the difference), but ultimately the page layout is going to change at each media query threshold. There's no reason this should bother users though - if they are changing the window size, they will be expecting a layout change.